# Should I re-use cursor object or create a new one with mysql.connector?

Tags: python-3.x, mysql-python, mysql-connector

Should I reuse the cursor object or create a new one for each query?

Reusing the cursor:

```py
    # we're going to connect to s3 and mysql
    db = mysql_connect(host="localhost",
                       user="user",
                       passwd="pass",
                       database="db")

    # Reusing the cursor
    cursor = db.cursor()

    # loop through all the files in the bucket one by one
    for key in bucket.get_all_keys():

        # the document id is the filename in the s3 bucket
        doc_id = key.name.split("/")[-1]
        cursor.execute("SELECT document_name FROM laws_docs WHERE id = %i", (doc_id,))
        doc_name = cursor.fetchone()[0]

    cursor.close()
```

- or -

New cursor every time:

```py
    # we're going to connect to s3 and mysql
    db =  mysql_connect(host="localhost",
                       user="user",
                       passwd="pass",
                       database="db")

    # loop through all the files in the bucket one by one
    for key in bucket.get_all_keys():

        # new cursor
        cursor = db.cursor()

        # the document id is the filename in the s3 bucket
        doc_id = key.name.split("/")[-1]
        cursor.execute("SELECT document_name FROM laws_docs WHERE id = %i", (doc_id,))
        doc_name = cursor.fetchone()[0]

         ursor.close()
```

Does it even matter?  That loop is going to run at least 50,000 times.

Answer (score 9):

If you're using [MySQL Connector/Python](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/), `cursor = db.cursor()` will create a new `CMySQLCursor` instance (or `MySQLCursor` if you're using the pure Python version). Thus for your second example, you will create 50,000 cursor instances.

You only need one cursor. Open and close the cursor outside the `for` loop (use your first example).